German tank problem variation - sequential game best strategy
Edit: a brief intro to the German tank problem: The German army has a bunch of tanks and you are trying to estimate the exact number. One day you see three tanks passing by with serial numbers x1, x2, and x3. You are trying to estimate what is the number N where N is the number of tanks that Germany has.
Similarly to the famous German tank problem, we still see three tanks with serial numbers $x_1,x_2,$ and $x_3$. Now you and I are playing a game like this: we both guess the number $N$ (total number of tanks) but not simultaneously. One of us goes first, and the second will know what is the first guess and then make their guess.
I got stuck on coming up with strategies for both player 1 and player 2 after getting the $\operatorname{EV} \left(\dfrac{4}{3} \cdot \max(x_1,x_2,x_3) - 1 \right)$. I'd say the distribution is skewed with more mass on the smaller end since the RHS of the mean extends to like infinite. But how should I proceed from here

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Adding what is the "German tank problem" to your question is recommended

It's hard to recommend a strategy when you don't tell us how it will be determined who wins.

This problem is a lot easier to think about when dealing with a simpler distribution (we will later map this approach onto the German Tank distribution from your original question).
Suppose that $x \sim \mathrm{U}(0, 1)$ and players $p_1,p_2,p_3$ each go sequentially picking a number and the one closest to $x$ wins. Where does each player go? Well we can clearly see that wherever $p_1$ and $p_2$ go, $p_3$ has the opportunity to go above the highest, below the lowest, or in between the two of them. If $p_3$ goes epsilon above the highest/below the lowest than the person that is epsilon away from $p_3$ will be disadvantaged in comparison to the other one of the first two people so $p_1$ and $p_2$ are clearly both incentivized to pick numbers such that $p_3$ goes in between the two of them.
This game is now symmetric with $p_1$ and $p_2$ which means that $p_3$ will pick $0.5$. $p_1$ and $p_2$ need to pick numbers such that $p_3$ is better off picking $0.5$ rather than epsilon above the highest/below the lowest. Even though it doesn't matter if $p_1$ is the one to pick the number above $0.5$ or if $p_2$ will, let's just say going forward that $p_1$ picks a number less than $0.5$.
$$p_1 = \frac{1 - 2p_1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$$
So when:
$$p_1=\frac{1}{4}, p_2=\frac{3}{4}, p_3=\frac{1}{2}$$ the game is in a perfect Nash Equilibrium. As discussion before though, by symmetry the following is equally as valid: $p_1=\frac{3}{4}$, $p_2=\frac{1}{4}$, and $p_3=\frac{1}{2}$.
You correctly asserted above that the German Tank distribution has some skew to it so we can't be symmetric about the MLE, but we can be symmetric about the percentiles of the distribution of the MLE. So we need to computer the PDF of the MLE and then pick a point that corresponds to the same point on the PDF as one would pick from the $\mathrm{U}(0, 1)$ distribution.
$$t_1, t_2, t_3 \sim \mathrm{U}(1, N), \quad \text{where } N \geq \max(t_1, t_2, t_3)$$
$$N_{\text{MLE}} = \max(t_1, t_2, t_3) + \frac{\max(t_1, t_2, t_3) - 1}{2}$$
$$P(N \mid t_1, t_2, t_3) \propto \frac{1}{N^3}, \quad \text{for } N \geq T, \quad \text{where } T = \max(t_1, t_2, t_3)$$
$$P(N \mid t_1, t_2, t_3) = \frac{\frac{1}{N^3}}{\zeta(3) - \sum_{k=1}^{T-1} \frac{1}{k^3}}$$
